# Как сделать отступы от краёв окна обозревателя до содержимого сайта?

Tags: html, css, width

[image: Как сделать отступы от краёв окна обозревателя до содержимого сайта?]
Для родительского («обёрточного») блока задано (рис. 1):

```
width: 100%;
max-width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Когда окно обозревателя становится меньше заданной max-width, нужно, чтобы были отступы справа и слева (рис. 2).

Решения нашлись такие:

1. задать padding/margin для body;
2. задать ширину для родительского («обёрточного») блока менее 100% (например, 90%).

Возможно, есть ещё варианты?

Comment: обычно делают через `{ border: 0 solid transparent; border-width: 0 40px; box-sizing: border-box; }` - что бы абсолютно спозиционированным элементам не надо было задавать разные отступы от краев для разных устройств (так как на мобильной обычно отсупые либо уменьшаются, либо вообще 0).

Comment: можно ещё так `width: calc(100vw - 80px);`

Comment: А вариант с padding/margin для body имеет место быть? Или так не делают?

Comment: Имеет место, просто я обычно в своей практике использую именно отступы самого .content-wrapper'a, как к этому пришел, честно говоря сейчас и не вспомню.

Comment: а, вспомнил как. Иногда приходится использовать .content-wrapper с `position: absolute/fixed;` (хоть и необязательно), тогда выручает, если отступы именно у него, а не у `body`

Comment: @MedvedevDev, в комментарии выше вы написали `width: calc(100vw - 80px)`, а в ответе — `width: calc(100% - 80px)`. Как я понимаю, значение 100% использовать правильнее (в данном случае)?

Comment: по сути да, 100% - размер видимой части окна, 100vw - размер окна браузера. То есть если у вас 1920 ширина экрана, браузер развернут на весь экран, и у вас есть на странице скролл, то 100% выдаст `1920px - ширина скроллбара`, а 100vw выдас  `1920px`. Плюс 100% - более гибко, так как можно использовать и внутри других блоков, а не только как "распорку контента"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  border-width: 0 40px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-2 {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.block_inner {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block_inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="block-2">
  <div class="block_inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 90%;
max-width: 800px;
margin: auto;
```

Comment: Ожидал от тебя фееричного способа, но по моему это то же самое, что описал автор в пункте 2

Comment: @MedvedevDev, разница в 90% вместо 100%. Если я правильно понял вопрос, то у него проблема в том, что при минимальной ширине полей нет.

Comment: "задать ширину для родительского («обёрточного») блока менее 100% (например, 90%)" - это цитата из вопроса.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, да, понял. Как всегда невнимательно читаю вопрос...

Comment: главное, что ваши вкусы на счет кол-ва процентов совпали xDDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev, просто визуально похоже по картинке :)